# How to create folder with unique name while running a JMeter command in non GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

I am running some jmeter tests through command line, and in that command I have the statement:

```
jmeter -n -t /abc.jmx -l /${START.HMS}Results.csv -e -o /${START.HMS}someFolder
```

which of course outputs the JMeter results into a file that is called `"xxxxResults.csv"` and its working fine for me.

**My question is:**

> Is there a way in the command line to give a unique name to the test results folder?

Because when I run the above command .csv file is getting generated, but the dashboard is not getting created with the name `${START.HMS}` some folder and seeing the following error in command line,

```
Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.core.SampleException: Could not locate input sample files!
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure  you have [`report-template` folder](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/trunk/bin/report-template) in the same place where you run JMeter from.

Alternatively you can set location of the folder containing JMeter report templates by amending `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.template_dir` property, it can be done either in *user.properties* file or via [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options).

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

---

Also be aware that your operating system doesn't know anything about `${START.HMS}` property, you will need to get current timestamp in other way, i.e. using [Time](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491015.aspx) command on Windows systems or [date](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/udate.htm) command on Linux/Unix/MacOSX